# Set control as first responder in other NSViewController

Tags: swift, macos

I have a window with 3 NSViewControllers in a splitview - effectively a 3 level master detail.
Inside each are, in order, an OutlineView, TableView and a details view (with
lots of controls).

When someone clicks on a row in the middle TableView, `SelectionDidChange`
fires, and I call `LoadData` on the details view controller.

I now want the details form to get focus - specifically an NSTextView
on that form. So in `LoadData`, I call `TextView.BecomeFirstResponder()`,
which returns true.

But focus stays firmly on the TableView, and does not move to the details view.
If I press a key, it goes to the TableView which uses it to select another row.

Is there something simple I am missing?
When one of the controls on the details view has focus, I can definitely
move focus between controls, but not from another view controller.

Thx.
Paul,

Comment: You have to call `window.setFirstResponder(view)` where `view` is the UI element.

Comment: If it doesn't work then read the documentation. [becomeFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1807130-becomefirstresponder?language=occ): "Use the NSWindow method makeFirstResponder:, not this method, to make a text view the first responder. Never invoke this method directly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your view controller view and `TextView` are already in window view hierarchy, do the following:

```
self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(TextView)
```

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thx - that was it.